# c# Diversification thread equally

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I am a C# programmer, and I run into some thread issue problem.

Assets are entities, and I need to run each asset parallel, and run a method "doSomethingOnAsset"

I have a program that has 100 thread (i.e 1 thread per asset I am doing on it some manipulations). Generally each thread has the same time frame on each intrval that is running, and each one call "doSomethingOnAsset" method.

Each thread interval is running 10 millisecond  (i.e).

I don't want so many threads, so I create one queue for each asset, but when calling the central method "doSomethingOnAsset" - the threads are not running in same time frame interval.

i.e the 1st thread running interval cycle is 300 milliseconds.
the 2nd thread running interval cycle is 700 milliseconds.
the 3rd thread running interval cycle is 2 seconds.
...

What is the best way running a predefined method 100 times parallel (the parallel entry may be an external service that when running, trigger an event that run my code of "doSomethingOnAsset".

```
public void doSomethingOnAsset(object obj)
{
   // infinite loop when thread. 
   while (true)
   {
      doSomething(obj);
      Thread.Sleep(100);
   }
}

public void doSomething(object obj)
{
   // do something.
}

public void Run()
{
    Thread t;            
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(this.doSomethingOnAsset));
        t.Start(new object());
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

or call doSomething on event signal, when an external program trigger.

Thanks :)

Comment: Side note. Why not `Parallel.For(...)`? Creating `100` threads explicitly is not a good design. Something like this: `Parallel.For(0, 100, i => doSomethingOnAsset(i));`

Comment: Either use `Parallel.For` or queue them all using the threadpool or with tasks, the parallelism should be taken care of automatically.

Comment: Do you have 100 cores? This doesn't sound like a good plan for optimising throughput.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the context of the timeframes and intervals? Your code does not suggest any form of intervals or timeframes at all.

Comment: Can you give me an example.
There are 100 (even more logically calls that must be parallel - I won't bring up 100 computers for that). Also - does parallel.for make 100 threads?

Comment: First of all, you're not using `i` for anything. Are you simply spinning up 100 identical methods? What is the point of that?

Comment: Either Parallel.For or ActionBlock<T> with a MaxDOP >1 can process data/messages in parallel. ActionBlock<T> buffers input messages so you should probably check it out

Comment: Sorry. I extended my code - The above doesn't work. Need a thread (each thread is infinite loop). Event calls only doSomething, but how can I do that?

Comment: @Eitan there's no reason to handle threads manually when the framework *already* provides this functionality. For example, creating 100 threads costs, which is why the framework provides a pool of threads. The result is *much* more scaleable code than what you can do by hand

Comment: For example, you can use two ActionBlocks, one for "Messages" and one for "Events". You can limit concurrent threads to the number of cores in your machine, or any other number. The block's buffer will receive all messages so you don't have to create your own buffer.

Comment: You can also *link* blocks, with a predicate that decides where to send each message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these kinds of producing-consumer situations I usually define a blocking collection, define and create a consumer (or multiple), and start adding data to the collection. Each consumer instance will try to take an item, and if any, consume it. Otherwise, it will wait for an item.

You could add a cancellation token to support to stop processing.

You can scale it easily by adding more consumers. Of course, what number is the most efficient depends on the machine and the number of cores, in combination with the processing-length-per-item.

The consumer:

```
public class MyConsumer<T> {
    public MyConsumer(BlockingCollection<T> collection, Action<T> action) {
        _collection = collection;
        _action = action;
    }

    private readonly BlockingCollection<T> _collection;
    private readonly Action<T> _action;

    public void StartConsuming() {
        new Task(Consume).Start();
    }

    private void Consume() {
        while (true) {
            var obj = _collection.Take();
            _action(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public void doSomething(object obj) {
   // do something.
}

public void Run() {
    var collection = new BlockingCollection<object>();

    // Start workers
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        new MyConsumer<object>(collection, doSomethingOnAsset);
    }

    // Create object to consume
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        collection.Add(new object());
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to use cold tasks ie `Task(Consume).Start()`, `Task.Run` will do. Also, need to *block* a task/thread waiting for input.The framework's ActionBlock already does this without blocking and much better control over buffering, DOP